# How to stop quartz cron scheduler after specified number of occurrences?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement where user can set a end date or can set a specific number of occurrences before stopping any job.

As for example,

Consider I have to send sms to a specific number and that should start from now and the sms will be sent in each 5 minutes.

Now based on user's choice the above job will be stopped on a specific time or after n number of occurrences.

And I am using cron scheduler of quartz.

Now stopping it at a specific date time is easy and I have done it like following way;

```
    trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                            .startAt(startDateObj)
                            .endAt(endDate)
                            .withIdentity(uniqueID, "group1")
                            .withSchedule(
                                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronString)
                                )
                            .build();
```

But what to do if I have to stop it after n number of occurrences? I know it can be done with simple schedule like;

```
simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(1).withIntervalInSeconds(15)
```

But how to do the same for cron scheduler? For some reasons I can not shift to any other type of schedule except cron.

Any help will be great for me.

Please let me know if any more data is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct way to do that.  The repeat count setting is related to the SimpleTrigger interface, which is not a parent interface for the CronTrigger.  The CronTriggerImpl class does not implement the SimpleTrigger interface.  The work around would be, as you already determined, to calculate the end date based on number of repetitions and address it that way.  Alternatively, you could track how many times the job executes (possibly in the JobDataMap), then have the job remove the trigger when it finishes the last desired execution.

Comment: Thanks for storing count into JobDataMap idea. :D. Earlier I was thinking to store into DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the `endDate` using `computeEndTimeToAllowParticularNumberOfFirings()` method. (That name though!).
See the following example:

```java
CronTrigger trigger = new Trigger()
                           .withIentity("some_id")
                           .withSchedule(buildCronScheduler("some_cron_exp"))
                           .build();
Date endDate = TriggerUtils.computeEndTimeToAllowParticularNumberOfFirings(
                    (OperableTrigger) trigger,
                    new BaseCalendar(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()),
                    repeatCount);
trigger = trigger.getTriggerBuilder().endAt(endDate).build();
```